# Is "terribly beautiful" a common use of the word terribly?

Tags: word-usage

My brother mentioned the phrase terrible in French is used for both good and bad sometimes. Is this true for English?

I have heard people use the phrase "terribly beautiful" in a context of describing something intensely beautiful. My brother says he has never heard this phrase and doesn't believe it's a legitimate usage. Although I don't personally use this phrase because it seems contradictory to me, I have heard it used.

Is that a common or accepted use of the word terrible in English?

Comment: it is terribly common.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that questions which are easily answerable by checking a dictionary are off-topic; for example, the first definition for *terribly* given by ODO is *[Very; extremely](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terribly)*.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that, but my brother wouldn't accept the OED listing. I was looking for something more substantive. I got that.

Comment: He said something to the effect of "no normal person" uses it, which I think he means its not a common slang usage.

Comment: It's not terribly common, but it's used.  It risks being misinterpreted.  Pretty much any intensity-modifying adverb is semantically valid (and semi-meaningful) with any adjective.

Comment: Technically it is correct usage. But I think few people would use *terribly*-meaning very or extremely - with the word *beautiful*. There are a vast number of alternatives, such as *exquisitely beautiful*, *very beautiful* etc. It would be far more likely to hear *terribly beautiful* used in the negative *she is not terribly beautiful*, a way of saying 'she is quite ordinary looking'.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=terribly+beautiful%2Cvery+beautiful%2Chauntingly+beautiful%2Cextremely+beautiful%2Cexceedingly+beautiful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cterribly%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chauntingly%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextremely%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexceedingly%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate that 'terribly beautiful' is **not** 'terribly common', @Oldcat. Having a correct definition doesn't guarantee accepted usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a legitimate usage that's been in use for more than 150 years:

See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=terribly+beautiful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cterribly%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0):
[image]

Comment: Note that about 1920 "incredibly beautiful" passed "terribly beautiful", and it has been zooming upwards ever since.

Comment: "Amazingly beautiful" also beats "terribly beautiful", though not by as much.

Comment: From a book published in 1853: "And terrible it was: from three several parts of the ruined city huge fires suddenly blazed up, hissing, crackling, ascending as clear columns of liquid flame; up against the pitchy darkness, infusing it with tenfold horror—spreading on every side—consuming all of wood and wall which the earth and water had left unscathed; wreathing its serpent-like folds in and out the ruins, forming strange and **terribly beautiful** shapes of glowing colouring; fascinating the eye with admiration, yet bidding the blood chill aud the flesh creep."

Comment: I think that many of the early instances of _terribly beautiful_ (like the one in my comment above) specifically intended the phrase to be understood as meaning "terrible and beautiful." More recently, though, I agree that the phrase is used in the sense of "very beautiful."

Comment: @SvenYargs- Yes, in fact I think it can mean both.   A girl might be described as being *terribly beautiful* by some boys who are terrified to speak to her because of how beautiful she is.  So "beautiful enough to induce terror" *is* intensely beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

It's becoming less and less common. That's just how it works, many words' meanings have literally changed over the years; however, this is one that has become less common in everyday speech.